# how to convert the string of list back to list of strings in python

Tags: python

In one of my dataset, I have the values
like this : `[freshdesk,wordpress,mailchimp,microsoft_office_365,greenhouse,nginx]` 
I want to convert them back to `["freshdesk","wordpress","mailchimp","microsoft_office_365","greenhouse","nginx"]`
for further processing

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How did you get that in your list?

Comment: There are 2 ways. First, you can use ast package’s literal_eval(). Second, if you want to do it manually. First do string.strip(‘[]’) to strip the brackets. Then, do string.split(‘,’) to split by comma. And you should be all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in your dataset is clean enough, then you can loop through them with the following transformation:

```
value = '[freshdesk,wordpress,mailchimp,microsoft_office_365,greenhouse,nginx]'
value = value[1:-1].split(',')

>>>value
['freshdesk', 'wordpress', 'mailchimp', 'microsoft_office_365', 'greenhouse', 'nginx']
```

`value[1:-1]` slices your original string to `'freshdesk,wordpress,mailchimp,microsoft_office_365,greenhouse,nginx'`

Then, when you split the string, it automatically partitions them into a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
s = '[freshdesk,wordpress,mailchimp,microsoft_office_365,greenhouse,nginx]'

re.findall('\w+', s)
['freshdesk',
 'wordpress',
 'mailchimp',
 'microsoft_office_365',
 'greenhouse',
 'nginx']
```